# What is the best way of ensuring that an async method can update a non-threadsafe collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I'm doing async calls that eventually will update a collection in the GUI. The async call is done from a delegate command like this:

```
StartDoingUsefulStuffCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Task.Run(() => StartDoingUsefulStuff()));

public async Task StartDoingUsefulStuff()
{
    try
    {
        await some method
        do something else
        MyCollection.Clear();
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // handle exception
    }
}
```

Eventually the StartDoingUsefulStuff method wants to update a collection, resulting in this exception because another thread tries to update a collection:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support
>   changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the
>   Dispatcher thread.

I've found one solution: Run the task in the current SynchronizationContext:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartDoingUsefulStuff(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This will work fine, but to me it seems tedious to do all this stuff each time a command is called from XAML. What are your opinions on my present solution/what are best practices?

Comment: Have a look at it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So you would recommend calling Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MyCollection.Clear())); ?

Comment: All I am saying is if you want to set UI values from different thread this might be an option. And it all depends on you how you use it.

Comment: Seems like you are modifying `MyCollection` while it is being used by a loop?

Comment: @rhughes Not necessarily, and not in this case

Comment: Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will return the dispatcher for the current thread (and will create one if called on a thread that does not have a Dispatcher). You have to know which thread you are on already to leverage it (and you must be on the thread where the object with thread affinity was created for it to work as you would want to use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already given the correct answer. The problem here is not that the collection is not thread-safe. The problem is that the collection cannot be modified by a thread other than the UI thread.

This is a common 'issue' with UI controls, whether it's WPF or WinForms.

The solution is indeed to pass the required options to run the task in the 'current synchronization context' which means (in WPF) that the completions are run in the thread that calls them, which is usually the UI thread.

You don't have to do this all the time. In fact, you're only doing it once, when you manually start the new task. The C# 5 'async' behavior by default does this too, which is why most of us have the tedious task of doing the reverse: tell the scheduler not to use the same synchronization context with the following code:

```
var result = await SomeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

There are issues to using the default behavior, including locking up your main thread, but in your case, it's exactly that what you want.

Maybe you should consider not calling Task.Run() but instead just call the async method directly (without Task.Run()) and discard the returned task object (i.e. fire-and-forget).

Comment: I like your explanation. However as for your last statement (not calling task.run), Unit Tests will fail randomly if the method is declared with async void. So, in order to avoid this I've started to use async Task for "callback methods"

Comment: Yes, it's possible that unit test runners do not support async, I've had problems with this myself. This doesn't mean that you need to be async in order to call an async function. A method only needs to be async if it wants to perform an await operation.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more simple way to fix it. In the constructor where your Collection is intialized just add the below line after initialization.

`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyCollection,_lock);` where `_lock` is a `private static object`. You don't have to take care of thread safety in your commands anymore then. You can then use the `await Task.Run` safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dispatcher object of "MyCollection"
Something like this:

```
MyCollection.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
{ 
    MyCollection.Clear()) 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some objects in .NET have thread affinity, typically to the thread that they were created on. This is why you are getting the NotSupportedException, because you're trying to alter an object with thread affinity from the wrong thread.

Essentially you need to make sure that any operation which may run into issues because of thread affinity is executed on the correct thread.

You can leverage the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object for an easy way to execute arbitrary code on a specific thread. If you are using ViewModels, you can require that they be injected with a Dispatcher (i.e. as a constructor parameter), representing the Dispatcher that the objects with thread affinity were created on.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        UIDispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    protected Dispatcher UIDispatcher;
}
```

Whenever you need to execute a piece of code that must occur on the UI thread, you can leverage the Dispatcher, and use the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods as appropriate.

Keeping a Dispatcher around seems to be the way that Microsoft deals with objects with thread affinity too. The CollectionView object that you are using has a Dispatcher property (inherited from DispatcherObject) that you can use to execute code on the appropriate thread.

```
MyCollection.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MyCollection.Clear()));
```

I would recommend not using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), unless you are absolutely certain that the operation will not require any meaningful amount of processing time. You want to keep as many operations **off** the UI thread as possible, in order to maintain a responsive UI. Using Tasks is a good way to do this, but using the TaskScheduler created from the UI thread is definitely the wrong way to solve the thread affinity problem, assuming that maintaining a responsive UI is important.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about "you can require that they be injected with a Dispatcher," and how you're planning to do it?

Comment: @emedbo Generally you maintain full control over the creation of your ViewModels, so you include a requirement for a valid Dispatcher object (i.e. as a Constructor parameter) and then sort it out at creation time. At the top level (or wherever you're creating your ViewModels) you identify the UI thread, and then make sure to inject that into the ViewModels as they are being created.